# Move data between listboxes when one gets values from table

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, listbox, postback

I have a webpage with 2 listboxes and I need to be able to move data back and forth between them. I had it working perfectly until I needed one of the listboxes (ColumnsList) to get its data from an Access DB.

The values are populated on the server side, so the jquery code I was using now always returns a count of the selected items as 0. I assume I would now need to move these items in the server side vb code. I was able to do that successfully, but that was then causing a postback of the form, which I cannot have.

I attempted to use javascript to call a webmethod to perform the move, but that won't work unless I use the "Public Shared Function" declaration, which then causes an issue with the listboxes not being able to be seen by the code (cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method...).

Anyway, here is the button control to move the items to the listbox on the right:

```
<button id="MoveRight" runat="server" style="position:absolute; left:845px; top:250px; width:30px; height:30px;" type="button">></button>
```

Here is the button declared on the server side:

```
Protected WithEvents MoveRight As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton
```

Here is my code-behind, server-side code:

```
Private Sub MoveRight() Handles MoveRight.ServerClick
    Dim LeftSideCount As Integer = 0
    Dim RightSideCount As Integer = 0
    Dim SelectedItemsArray(111) As ListItem


    For x As Integer = 0 To ColumnsList.Items.Count - 1
        If ColumnsList.Items.Item(x).Selected Then
            LeftSideCount += 1
            SelectedItemsArray(x) = ColumnsList.Items.Item(x)
        End If

    Next

    For y As Integer = 0 To SelectedColumns.Items.Count - 1
        RightSideCount += 1
    Next

    If LeftSideCount + RightSideCount <= 15 Then
        'move items right

        For z As Integer = 0 To LeftSideCount - 1
            SelectedColumns.Items.Add(SelectedItemsArray(z))

            ColumnsList.Items.Remove(SelectedItemsArray(z))

        Next

    Else
        'don't move items right
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there any way I can do this without a postback occurring?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions anyone may have!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Originally I thought that this:

[How to prevent page being postbacked when i transfer item from one listbox to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174880/how-to-prevent-page-being-postbacked-when-i-transfer-item-from-one-listbox-to-ot?rq=1)

wouldn't work in my case as there were several differences between what that poster and I were trying exactly to do. It turns out, however, that this is the solution I needed. Thanks anyway!